# How do I insert a UIImage view in a return statement in a function?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In this part of my code, I am trying to insert a UIImage inside the footer to separate my 2 tables. The commented lines above the return part are the codes that I have tried but yet showed error. Even for the line of *"let image:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "white")!
            return image"* I am still unable to make it work. The error that I have been receiving is *"Cannot convert return expression of type 'UIImage' to return type 'String?'"*. I have saved the image as "white" and in png format.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        if ftSubjs.count == 0 {
            return "No Classes Today"
        }
        else {
            //return UIImageView.init(image: "white")
            //return UIImageView.image = (resourceName: "white")
            //return UIImage(named: "white.png")
            //return "_"
            let image:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "white")!

            return image
        }
    }
    else {
        if ptSubjs.count == 0 {
            return "No Classes Today"
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

*I was trying to add an extra space at the bottom of the table hence the reason I was using the white image. I forgot that I could do that with just a click on the space bar. If anyone is looking for such solution, add a space in the return statement to look like this (guarantee it will work!):

```
            return " "
```

Comment: You need to return a `String`, not a `UIImage`. Look at the method signature. Perhaps you mean to use `viewForFooterInSection` instead of `titleForFooterInSection`.

Comment: thank you for your comment @rmaddy but i dont understand why i would have to use string when im intending to insert an image. also, i have tried your suggestion of using viewForFooterInSection but it cleared the other return values of "No Classes Today"

Comment: Look at the return values of those two methods. Then look at the documentation for those two methods.

Comment: did you mean titleForFooterInSection requires string in its return and viewForFooterInSection allows for a UIImage? if its such the case then would my situation be unsolvable seeing that i need the white image in the footer to separate my tables? @rmaddy

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to return UIImage

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
    let infolabel = UILabel(frame: bgView.frame)
    infolabel.text = "No Classes Today"
    if section == 0 {
        if ftSubjs.count == 0 {
            return bgView.addSubview(infolabel)
        }
        else {
            //return UIImageView.init(image: "white")
            //return UIImageView.image = (resourceName: "white")
            //return UIImage(named: "white.png")
            //return "_"
            let image:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "white")!
            return bgView.addSubview(image)
        }
    }
    else {
        if ptSubjs.count == 0 {
            return bgView.addSubview(infolabel)
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```